# Entering relations to database using Persistent

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

Starting out with Haskell and Yesod, probably getting a bit too far with Yesod relative to Haskell :)

I build entities using Persistent via

```
share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"][persistLowerCase|
Game
  title String
  company String
  UniqueTitle title
  deriving Show
Tag
  label String
  description String Maybe
  UniqueLabel label
  deriving Show
GameTag
  gameId GameId
  tagId TagId
  UniqueGameTag gameId tagId
|]

-- Yesod related code ...
```

In main  I have

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
let taggings = fromFile :: [(Game, Tag)] -- fromFile code not included
runStderrLoggingT $ withSqlitePool ":inmemory:" 10 $ λpool →  liftIO $ do
runResourceT $ flip runSqlPool pool $ do
  runMigration migrateAll
  let (g, t) = head taggings
  gid ←  insert g
  tid ←  insert t
  insert (GameTag gid tid)
warp 3000 $ App pool
```

Doing this I get the first relation into the database, and by selecting elements from the list I can add more 'by hand', but I can't figure out how to get all the relations into the database by somehow iterating over `taggings`. How do i define a function that I can map over `taggings ::[(Game, Tag)]` and inserts the game tags of the type `GameTag` constructed
by Persistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main trick here isn't in pulling out the function, that is easy:

```
f (g, t) = do
  gid <- insert g
  tid <- insert t
  insert (GameTag gid tid)
```

The trick is knowing how to use this....  Standard `map` won't work alone, because the function is defined in a monad (you can use it, it will just give you a list of actions back without running them).

```
map f taggings -- returns just a list, type [ResourceT IO a], doesn't run anything
```

---

Here are two ways to actually run the actions from within main.

```
sequence (map f taggings) --sequentially runs the actions in the list
```

or, the more readable

```
forM taggings f
```

or, in the slightly more verbose

```
forM taggings $ \tagging -> do
  f tagging
```

You also might want to look at `mapM`.  Also also should learn about `forM_` and `sequence_` to supress the (often useless) return values.